# Direct forecast using epsilion-SVR

Tags: matlab, time-series, libsvm, forecasting

Is it possible to predict directly into the future using epsilion-svr?

My dataset is a univariate time series and has per line a record in this format:

`Y(t-W), Y(t-W+1), ..., Y(t), Y(t+PH)`

**`W`** is the number of time steps to consider

**`PH`** controls how many steps into the future I want to forecast.

Is this valid for `PH > 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Support-Vector-Regression based predictor is used for exactly that.

It shall stand for `PH >= 1`.

The value of `epsilon` in the epsilon-SVR model specifies the epsilon-tube, within which no penalty is associated in the training loss function with points predicted within a distance `epsilon` from the actual value `Y(t)`.

```
model = svmtrain( Y_targets,      %% Mx1 vector of the training data target response values,
                  X_trainSamples, %% MxN matrix of the training samples, having N features, where N = W + 1
                  param           %% ref. below
                  );
```

**`param`** is a string which specifies the model parameters.

For Regression, a typical parameter string may look like,
`‘-s 3 -t 2 -c 20 -g 64 -p 1’` where

```
-s svm type,        3 for epsilon-SVR
-t kernel type,     2 for radial basis function
-c cost parameter C of epsilon-SVR
-g width parameter gamma for RBF kernel
-p epsilon for epsilon-SVR
```

Anyway, check your SVR-implementation detailed documentation on further details.

Comment: When predicting future values using svmpredict function we provide the label in the training stage. Why? Is it just to have the MSE and the autocorrelation results of the training data? When we want to test the model with the test data is it okay to give a random value right?

Comment: Well, SVR-predictors serve values, not labels as Classifier-oriented predictors. Training dataset is needed to develop the process of minimising the SVR-penalty function and provide the set of Support-Vectors. Cross-validation helps further to a better adjustment of the learner's parameters so that the generalisation and over-fitting get better and allow the predictor to better handle Out-of-Sample data ( beyond the Training Epoch of the TimeSeries ).

Comment: I cannot understand how is it possible to make cross validation on a time series. Is the order of the records in the dataset not important? We just have to maintain the order within each record? Regarding the epsilon parameter, can it be defined _a prior_ knowing the kind of problem we are dealing with, right?

Comment: Cross-Validation works the same way as on other datasets. You might want to know, that StackOverflow Community encourages to **ask as another question** if interested in any additional topic(s) so as to prevent a "creep" and "broadening" the original subject-under-focus in the original post.